# VB.net datagridview color based on how many days from today

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, columnsorting

So basically what i want to get is a payment system for rental property.

I have made a database(in access for ease of work) and i'm now looking for a way to compare the date in the datagridview to today's date. If the date of the last payment is 30 days behind, it has to turn red. If its <30 it should stay green.

Now i'm wondering how to do that, because I can't seem to get it to work.

Since i'm fairly new to the vb.net-language I didn't get anything to work. I figured posting any code would be useless since it's all underlined with red and my program won't even run.

I figured it would be something in the style of

`If me.dgv.columns("1") > 30:
      me.dgv.row.defaultcellstyle.color = "red"
End if`

The dates are sorted/displayed in an ascending fashion, not sure if that might help?

Any help would be of great value and I thank you in advance!

Comment: I suggest, as the first step, to open up your project's properties and set `Option Strict On`, if not already set. It'll help you a lot to understand when you're off beat. If you're uncertain on the syntax, click on a keyword and press `F1`. The on-line help often provides ready-to-test examples. Go see the [DataGridView.CelFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting) event, for example. That's the event commonly used to perform specific cell formatting, like changing the Fore/Back color on a condition.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you could do that, what does `Option Strict On` do?

Comment: `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` (in combination) prevent your code to accept declaration/assignments that could/will produce wrong values at run-time. `Option Strict Off`, for example allows you to write `Dim x = 1 : Dim y = "3" : x = y`. Well, you can say, `x` will be set to `3` (integer). But you could then do `Dim z = y + y : x = z`. Now, what's the value of `x`? Read more about Late Binding and narrowing convertions in [Compile Page, Project Designer (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/compile-page-project-designer-visual-basic).

Comment: These options set to `ON` force you to never forget about your types and their usage. This is a simple example. When it comes to objects (classes and such), these *interpretations* could become problematic and difficult to trace, in case of run-time errors (more if you're not used to it). Setting them to `ON` from the beginning, you and your code will be forced to be *aware* of every type declaration/assignment/conversion and, in the end, much more *reliable*.

Answer (score 2):

- to check 30 days later you use `date.Now.addDays(30)`
- to check 30 days before you use `date.Now.addDays(-30)`
- to color the cell forecolor you use something like this:

  `For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
      If CDate(dr.Cells(0).Value) > Date.Now.AddDays(30) Then
      dr.Cells(0).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
      End If
  Next`

you can also loop the cells to check all DGV cells for dates and compare them

Comment: Working perfect! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it is best to handles this in RowPrePaint event.

Example:

```
        Public Class Test
            Private Shared Rnd As New Random

            Private Sub FormControls_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                'Start Sample
                DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {
                                          .Name = "MyDate",
                                          .ValueType = GetType(DateTime)})
                For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
                    'create random dates in the past
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Now.AddDays(-Rnd.Next(0, 25)))
                Next
                'End Sample
            End Sub

            Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPrePaint
                Dim DgvRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

                With DgvRow
                    If DgvRow IsNot Nothing AndAlso DgvRow.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso DgvRow.Cells(0).Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
                        If Now.Subtract(CDate(DgvRow.Cells(0).Value)).TotalDays > 20 Then
                            DgvRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        Else
                            DgvRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty
                        End If
                    End If
                End With

            End Sub


        End Class
```